# Docker RUN apt-get install - Unable to locate package

Tags: dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile which is calling `RUN apt-get install guile-2.0-dev`

This script is executed from Ubuntu 20.04.4LTS using the command `"sudo docker build -f./Dockerfile -ttest:one ./"`. It shows the error:

```
E: Unable to locate package guile-2.0-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'guile-2.0-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'guile-2.0-dev'"
```

But other `apt-get` install commands called from Dockerfile works as expected. I am able to run `apt-get install guile-2.0-dev` command from my terminal. Can you please help me to figure out the reason for it fail inside the docker script?

A sample script is given below. `Bison` is installed successfully, but `guile` fails

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update


ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y bison

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y guile-2.0-dev
```

Comment: Do you run `apt-get update` before trying the installs? Clean Docker images usually don't have a populated `apt` cache. Like does `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y guile-2.0-dev` work for you?

Comment: I tried it now, but did not work. Threw same error

Comment: Can you show your `Dockerfile` in your post?

Comment: could you please update docker file in question? It might me some image depending on guile-2.0-dev have not added apt-get update in their dockerfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Dockerfile` pulls `ubuntu` which defaults to `latest` tag, which is `jammy-jellyfish/22.04`. `guile-2.0-dev` doesn't exist in that version, it was upgraded to `guile-2.2-dev`, so you'd want to do `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y guile-2.2-dev`.

```
FROM ubuntu

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y bison guile-2.2-dev
```

If you specifically need `guile-2.0-dev`, you will need `FROM ubuntu:focal` (v20.04) or `FROM ubuntu:bionic` (v18.04) depending on what Ubuntu you want.

```
FROM ubuntu:focal

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y bison guile-2.0-dev
```

---

Also see the ubuntu packages list: https://packages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search_packages.pl?keywords=guile&searchon=names&release=all

```
Package guile-2.0-dev

    bionic (18.04LTS) (lisp): Development files for Guile 2.0
    2.0.13+1-5build2: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
    bionic-updates (lisp): Development files for Guile 2.0
    2.0.13+1-5ubuntu0.1: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
    focal (20.04LTS) (lisp): Development files for Guile 2.0 [universe]
    2.0.13+1-5.4: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
```

```
Package guile-2.2-dev

    bionic (18.04LTS) (lisp): Development files for Guile 2.2 [universe]
    2.2.3+1-3build1: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
    bionic-updates (lisp): Development files for Guile 2.2 [universe]
    2.2.3+1-3ubuntu0.1: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
    focal (20.04LTS) (lisp): Development files for Guile 2.2
    2.2.7+1-4: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
    impish (21.10) (lisp): Development files for Guile 2.2
    2.2.7+1-6build1: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
    jammy (22.04LTS) (lisp): Development files for Guile 2.2
    2.2.7+1-6build2: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
    kinetic (lisp): Development files for Guile 2.2 [universe]
    2.2.7+1-6build2: amd64 arm64 armhf ppc64el s390x
```

Answer (score 0):

this works well with latest Ubuntu version

```
apt-get install -y guile-2.2-dev
```

you probably need to freeze the Ubuntu version you use and you can optimise your Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y bison guile-2.0-dev
```

UPDATE:

there is also https://packages.ubuntu.com site to find packages, for instance

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=guile-2.0-dev&searchon=names

Comment: yes, I am calling `apt-get update`, but the install fails !

Comment: edited my initial answer @LittleTree

Comment: Thanks for the input @Mikhail Tokarev. It helped me to solve the problem